# Move avro data in kafka to hive and then to hbase

Tags: hive, apache-kafka, avro

I did put my data to mysql but now am trying to put them to hive.
I could not find the right resources to begin with, so I am stuck now. The data am trying to work with is Avro.

I am doing in Java. Any help to where to start with would be really helpful

Comment: You can use sqoop from mysql directly to HBase. Why do you need Kafka or Hive?

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 I am looking to deserialize the avro messages in kafka and save them to hive.
The reason is I just want to experiment it and see how it works. I don't see any straight forward method to do that.

Comment: I am not sure if there is anyway actually to deserialize avro and save it to hive.

Comment: That's exactly what Confluent's hdfs kafka connector can do, assuming you're using the schema registry

Comment: Yes, but if I am implementing that in a cloudera machine, the schema registry is not available, am I right?

Comment: You can install Schema Registry onto any Kafka cluster, but if you're not using it, then the only other options I am aware of would be using NiFi or Spark

Comment: I have installed Schema Registry through confluent hub, but still am not getting how will I write the date the date to hive via kafka. Can you suggest me any good articles for it.
I do not want to use spark right now. I am sticking to java to produce and consume and then deserialize them and save to hive.

Comment: @cricket_007 Should I use a streaming service like Spark to push the data to hive?

Comment: As mentioned, Kafka Connect for HDFS from Confluent can create Hive tables, which can be found in Confluent Hub as well